# Incrementing NPM/Grunt version on successful build -- Bamboo

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a Bamboo server that is currently setup to test my builds on my project. 
I want to start versioning my project using NPM version or grunt bump.

Here is the current Bamboo setup I have,

1. Bamboo detects repo change
2. Runs all the test
3. If the branch is the 'master' branch, then do a post job of moving our production code into an artifactory (we just zip up the appropriate files and drop them into it).

I would like to be able to increment the version between step 2 and 3 if the branch is 'master'.

I'm trying to come up with a good solution for this.

I'm wondering if something like just doing npm version or npm bump is enough? It seems that I would want to them commit that back to the git repo?

Looking for some possible suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First detect that you're on the master branch. If so, do an `npm version` update. You also need to tell git to push to the remote repository rather than to the repo cached on the Bamboo server. For example, in a script task on your build plan:

```
npm install
npm run build

if [[ "${bamboo.planRepository.branchName}" == "master" ]]; then
    
    # configure git to use the remote repo
    git remote set-url origin ${bamboo.planRepository.1.repositoryUrl}
    rm .git/objects/info/alternates
    git fetch

    # update the local version
    # this will increment the last version number, commit and tag the commit
    npm version patch

    # create your artifact
    npm pack

    # push the version update
    git push
    git push --tags    
fi
```

Comment: This will actually get you in an endless loop of Bamboo bumping a version on master, then detecting that remote has changes, pulling, bumping again, etc... It needs [skipci] too:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Skip-Bamboo-builds-using-commit-message/qaq-p/867248